# frcursive package scaling

Tags: fonts, scale

I recently found this package `frcursive` which I think gives beautiful caligraphic letters.

The only problem is when I try to use it, the capital calligraphic letters are too big compared to normal capital letters ! Can anyone help me scaling them down, leaving the lowercase letter untouched ?

Here is a MWE

```
\documentclass[12pt, a4paper]{article}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage{frcursive}
\begin{document}
\cursive{A}A
\end{document}
```

Thanks for the help

T.D

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You can load the fonts at a suitable scale (2/3 seems good).

```latex
\documentclass[12pt, a4paper]{article}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}

\DeclareFontFamily{T1}{frc}{}
\DeclareFontShape{T1}{frc}{m}{n}{%
  <-8>   s*[0.6667] frcr6
  <8-14> s*[0.6667] frcr10
  <14->  s*[0.6667] frcr14
}{}
\DeclareFontShape{T1}{frc}{m}{sl}{%
  <-8>   s*[0.6667] frcsl6
  <8-14> s*[0.6667] frcsl10
  <14->  s*[0.6667] frcsl14
}{}
\DeclareFontShape{T1}{frc}{m}{it}{<-> ssub*frc/m/sl}{}
\DeclareFontShape{T1}{frc}{bx}{n}{%
  <-8>   s*[0.6667] frcbx6
  <8-14> s*[0.6667] frcbx10
  <14->  s*[0.6667] frcbx14
}{}
\DeclareFontShape{T1}{frc}{bx}{sl}{%
  <-8>   s*[0.6667] frcbxsl6
  <8-14> s*[0.6667] frcbxsl10
  <14->  s*[0.6667] frcbxsl14
}{}
\DeclareFontShape{T1}{frc}{bx}{it}{<-> ssub*frc/bx/sl}{}

\DeclareRobustCommand{\cursive}{\fontfamily{frc}\selectfont}
\DeclareTextFontCommand{\textcursive}{\cursive}

\begin{document}

\textcursive{ABCD}A

\textit{\textcursive{ABCD}A}

\textbf{\textcursive{ABCD}A}

\end{document}
```

[image]

About scaling only the uppercase letters, I don't think that it can give a nice result: it's pretty ugly, to be honest:

[image]

Comment: thanks @egreg for the help. Is it posible to scale only the capital letters, leaving the lowercase letters with normal scale ?

Comment: @T.D. In restricted circumstances. Do you need accented characters?

Comment: yes, I do, does it change a lot ?

Comment: @T.D. I added a screen shot from an attempt to scale down just the upper case letters: I don't think it's something that can be accepted.

Comment: ok Thanks a lot for the work, I will only use one case (upper or lower) per document, therefore I would like to thank you again for the work!

Answer (score 3):

```
\documentclass[12pt, a4paper]{article}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage{frcursive}
\makeatletter
\renewenvironment{cursive}{%
  \fontencoding{\frcursive@enc}%
  \fontfamily{frc}%
  \fontsize{9pt}{10pt}%
  \linespread{1.5}%
  \selectfont}{\par}
 \makeatother
\begin{document}
A \begin{cursive} A \end{cursive}
\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: Well, try `{\Large A\textcursive{A}}`